# How to set Yii2/Kartik/Bootstrap DatePicker in JQuery

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have the following Yii2 code to output a Kartik DateTime widget:

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'expiry_date')->widget(
    DatePicker::className(), [
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy'
    ]
]); ?>
```

I am trying to set it with the following JQuery code:

```
$( "#record-expiry_date").datepicker("setStartDate", new Date());
```

But unfortunately I just cannot get this to work - the value is never set.  I have tried multiple permutations based on solutions found online (such as setDate, using the .change() method, etc, etc) but none of have worked for me.

I can use the .val method like so:

```
$( "#record-expiry_date").val("01 Dec 2010");
```

And although this sets the date text box correctly, the calendar widget doesn't seem to have properly "registered" it (i.e. it still shows dates for this year when opened).

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I'm doing it is by basically using the Methods documented in the bootstrap Datepicker documentation, here: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update

So in your case the JS call would look like this, replacing the original `datepicker()` with `kvDatepicker()`:

```
$("#record-expiry_date").kvDatepicker("update", new Date(2010, 12, 01));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I used the following for jQuery and it works:  `$("#record-expiry_date").kvDatepicker("update", new Date());`  Could you please tell me where this gem is documented?  I can see no mention in http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker and http://demos.krajee.com/datecontrol currently leads to a dead end!

Comment: Glad it worked :)
It's documented here: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update
Basically Kartik's Datepicker is an "extension" of that boostrap-datepicker so supports most of those methods.

Comment: Thank you, but I was wondering how you know about the 'kvDatepicker' method?  Do all of Kratik's methods start with 'kv'?  Is there some sort of standard or documentation?  I have trapsed the web and this is the first time I've seen this method mentioned.

Comment: Oh that! I just looked at the JS sources of the plugin ;)
Don't think there's any actual documentation for the JS methods. At least I couldn't find any either. Hence reading his sources to figure it out ;)

Comment: Basically if you look in this js-file: ```vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker/assets/js/datepicker-kv.js``` you'll see the ```kvDatepicker()``` function being declared.

Comment: Great - the documentation involves wading through code.  Just what my sanity needed  ;)  This post will be useful for others, no doubt!  Thanks again!

Comment: You can do following as well
$("#record-expiry_date").datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                todayHighlight: true,
                startDate: startDate,
            });